# Mathematica nested loops

Tags: signal-processing

I can write down the following Python code:

```
for j1 > 2:
    time1 = i1
for i2 > i1:
    if j2  < 2:
        time2 = i2
break
```

Purpose of the above code:

```
Consider a set of touples M = [(i1,j1),(i2,j2),(i3,j3),etc]
```

what I want to do is (because in my case i = time and j = some physical value) isolate the interval in which my physical value is above the value 2. I want to be able to say, at the end, that the physical value j is above 2 for exactly 2.5 seconds, for example.

I wrote in in python code above, does anyone know how to rewrite it in Mathematica code?

Comment: Can there be multiple intervals where `j > 2`?

Comment: Why are you repeatedly setting `time1=i1` when `i1` is not being iterated over?

Comment: Marius: no, there is only one interval. Patrick: because (i1,j1) are part of a tuple, so it makes sense to iterate over j1, but then i1 depends on the value of j1. In Mathematica this would be a table of pairs.

Comment: I don't understand your Python code (did you mean `if` instead of `for`?), but `Cases[list, {i_, j_} /; j > 2]` selects those pairs where $j > 2$.  Then sort by $i$ (`SortBy`) and take the first and last elements.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you elaborate and maybe show a numerical example of what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica, there's no need to do this looping over indices.  Say your data is a list of tuples ordered in time:

```
testdata = Table[{x, 5 - .1 (x - 7.)^2}, {x, 0, 15, .1}];
ListLinePlot@%
```

[image]

Now you just need to `Select` the portion which meets the criterion.  `Select[testdata, #[[2]] > 2 &]` will return the tuples whose second value is greater than 2,  and

```
Select[testdata, #[[2]] > 2 &][[{1, -1}, 1]]

(*  {1.6, 12.4}  *)
```

returns the first and last time points whose value was greater than 2.